# How to make a while loop throughout entire code. (Python)

Tags: python, function, while-loop, break

I'm currently making a text-based game about walking through an abandoned house, and finding items to ward of monsters and all of that. I want a while loop system where if your health reaches below 0 (`health=20`), then the code ends by saying `"You died to (insert event here)"`. I'm new to coding with python, so I'm not entirely sure how to code that.

I've tried setting up a while loop with an if statement that checks if the health is below 0. This is near the top of the code below the variables and above the functions

```
health = 20 #variable

while ( health < 0):
    print("You died to [insert event here]\n")
    break
```

Instead of it doing anything, it completely ignores it. I'm not sure how I would place the code into the function because I still need to use "global" to import variables into them. If you know the answer to this problem, or you know an alternative code to solve this problem, please tell me. Again I'm new to python so please explain in a way I can understand.

Comment: any details on how are you updating the `health` value in general?

Comment: I'm confused by your statements towards the end of your question. Maybe you should restructure it to make more clear what your actual problem is. The first thing that comes to my mind when reading your question is: Make a loop that asks whether the player is still alive (while `health > 0`) and exit the loop and print your text when he is dead.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `global` keyword is only to give a function *write* access to a variable. They can always read variables which have been declared outside the scope of any other class/function.

What I think you want is the following:

- check health
- run the rest of the code
- check health
- run the rest of the code

ad infinitum...

What you are currently doing, as described, is:

- check health
- run the rest of the code

How you're going to do this is:

```
while(health > lower_limit):
    [the rest of the code]

print("you died") # game over
```

In this way, "while the health is above the lower limit, [the rest of the code] will run".

Answer (score 0):

You may write it as:

```
health = 20
while health > 0:
    print("You died to XYZ")
    health -= 1
```

This will print `"You died to XYZ"` 20 times as loop will run for 20 times from health = 20 to health = 0.

But, while health < 0 would consider it to be zero outcome because python understand loop to run till health reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good place to explain in detail why that code doesn't work. Instead, consider the following game as an example:

```py
def adventure_around(pit_limit = 5, initial_position = 0):
    position = initial_position
    lived = False
    print("Try not to die, noob!")
    while position < pit_limit:
        direction = input("Which way would you like to go? [n,s,e,w, or q]:")
        if direction not in ['n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'q']:
            print("Please choose a direction.")
            continue
        if direction == "n":
            position += 1
        if direction == 's':
            position -= 1
        if direction == "q":
            print("Coward! (You lived, though.)")
            lived = True
            break
    if not lived:
        print("You fell into a pit and died while bravely wandering about! RIP")

adventure_around()
```

Feed that to your python interpreter and play around with it. (Minutes of fun!) Then study the code. (Googling isn't cheating, either!) What does the `while` keyword do? How is information from the outside code conveyed to the function? Why are there two ways to exit the `while` loop? Was that a good idea? Is there a better way to update the position? Did `lived` need to be initialized? Why or why not? Go ahead and modify it to suit your purpose, if you can. While I don't think a *global* `health` variable is the best way to go, try to change the code so that it uses the `global` keyword to reference a global `health` variable. What error messages did you get while getting that to work? How would you manage that in a much larger game with tens, hundreds, or thousands of files?

Good hunting!